# how to write nginx conf file for angular app with Leverage browser

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, browser, dockerfile

After building the angular app,

when I run the docker file, I'm not able to load the page,

inside my console it gives me this waring:

[image]

Here is my nginx-custom.conf file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   location / {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.html index.htm;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
   }
   location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
       expires 365d;
   }
}
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM nginx:1.13
COPY  dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Expires map
  map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
  default                    off;
  text/html                  epoch;
  text/css                   max;
  application/javascript     max;
  ~image/                    max;
  }

  server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
 }
```

here is the reference [url](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-ubuntu-16-04)